# Roblox Studio :GetJoinData Issues

Tags: lua, scripting, roblox

So I'm trying to make a script that teleports a user to a "Portal" game, which then teleports that user to the placeId. I tried this but it didn't work, does anyone know how to fix it?

**LocalScript (main game)**

```
script.Parent.MouseButton1Click:Connect(function()
    local teleportOptions = Instance.new("TeleportOptions")
    local data = {
        placeId = 15391895047,
    }
    teleportOptions:SetTeleportData(data)
    game:GetService("TeleportService"):Teleport(13735957683, game.Players.LocalPlayer, data)
end)
```

**Script (portal game)**

```
game.Players.PlayerAdded:Connect(function(plr)
    print("User has joined")
    local tp_data = plr:GetJoinData()
    if tp_data then
        print("User has data")
        print(game:GetService("HttpService"):JSONEncode(tp_data))
        local placeId = tp_data.placeId
        if placeId ~= nil then
            print(placeId)
            wait(5)
            game:GetService("TeleportService"):TeleportAsync(tonumber(placeId), plr)
        else
            plr:Kick("You cannot directly join this experience. Missing valid placeId.")
        end
    else
        plr:Kick("Failed to fetch join data. Please try again later.")
    end
end)
```